# android osmdroid hide labels like country names, cities

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have been searching for hours now but it seems that I have not found a solution to my problem. I havesuccessfully displayed the map but my problem is that I would like to hide country names, cities etc on osmdroid? Is that possible?

Comment: the tiles(maps) that you get from the server are mostly static png images. It does not come as map and text separately. Try exploring on vector tiles

Comment: @dnivra thanks or answering! It helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained by user dnivra you cannot influence the style of [raster tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). But you can use a different tile provider, for example tiles.wmflabs.org/osm-no-labels provided by Wikimedia. You can view them [here](http://mc.bbbike.org/mc/?lon=13.368594&lat=52.459748&zoom=10&num=2&mt0=osm-no-labels&mt1=mapnik) on the left side. Alternatively you can [set up your own tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) allowing you to use your own styles.